# php built in function disables errors

Tags: php, error-handling

I found that any errors that occur after calling `odbc_prepare` are suppressed. I cannot get them to display. What I'm using to intentionally throw an error for testing:

```
 strpos(); //creates expected error
```

**Proof that my script is executing**

```
$statement = odbc_prepare($this->odbcResource,$sql);
error_log("hello"); //prints to the log just fine, so the script is executing to this point
```

**Breaks:**

```
$statement = odbc_prepare($this->odbcResource,$sql);
strpos(); // DOES NOT CREATE ERROR, PHP just returns a generic 500 Internal Server Error
```

I have tried creating a custom error handler, works until `odbc_prepare` is called. I have tried turning errors back on `incase odbc_prepare` was turning them off, didn't work. This is killing me since some error is happening much farther down and it's a pain to debug without any information.

EDIT:

I created my own error handler to test the issue. In the error handler I did a simple echo "hello"; That worked, indicating to me that the error handler is being used. Oddly, none of the error handler parameters, like the error string ect populated. In addition to that, I tried throwing an exception from here and that didn't bubble up, just got the standard 500.

Comment: try checking out the ini value for `display_errors` before and after. the odbc call. `ini_get('display_errors')`. Typically if you are getting just a 500 error, `display_errors` is set to false so the errors are not displayed and just written to the webserver error log.

Comment: I just verified that ini_get('display_errors') is true.